# Why are piezoelectric sensors called high impedance?

Tags: impedance

Piezoelectric mics and accelerometers are called high impedance aka high Z sensors. And I know that the high impedance sensor output needs to be converted into a low impedance signal first. I think this impedance transformation is needed for carrying the signal with minimum power loss.

But my question is more fundamental here. Let’s take a piezoelectric accelerometer/mic/sensor and model it. As far as I know it is modeled as a voltage source with a series capacitor. Something like:

[image]

Now if my model is correct for a piezoelectric sensor, why are these called high impedance sensors? Obviously Xc is frequency dependent which means it is hard to say whether the impedance is high or low here. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Look at the typical capacitance and the typical frequencies.

Comment: Please gimme a hint on these

Comment: What is a crystal dielectric? Answer: an insulator with piezo properties

Comment: the range of frequencies it's sensitive to is not infinite

Comment: @dandavis if it is buffered will the range of frequencies it's sensitive be almost infinite?

Comment: no, physics. the moving parts have mass, and excessive force to overcome that inertia will eventually melt the device

Comment: But I think if this is buffered since the buffer has almost infinite input impedance I guess then the signal will not attenuate at low frequencies.

Comment: @HelpMee No, because if the stress across the crystal develops too slowly, the voltage generated will be too small and just disappear into the thermal noise of the crystal and buffer.

Comment: @Toor But what is the solution then? What is done to obtain amplify and transmit low frequencies?

Comment: @HelpMee The solution is to use a different type of sensor more suited to the purpose. If you want to measure what is basically DC, then do not use an AC coupled sensor. Or you have to excite/chop the sensor so that the sensor never actually reads DC and then compensate for that in your final reading. That's not always possible though, especially with a piezoelectric sensor. It's more for something like a pyroelectric crystal (which also exhibits piezoelectric properties).

Comment: They are called high impedance because they are typically charge output not voltage, and hence look like an AC current source

Comment: @sstobbe But to see whether it is high or low impedance it must be modeled. If my model is wrong please provide a circuit model and we can see why it is high impedance. Just saying it is high impedance doesn’t satisfy me. I need to see this in a model. Can you write an answer showing that explicitly?

Comment: Assume 0.03 uF or 30,000 pF. The impedance of 1uF at 1 Hertz is -j159,000 ohms. At 1,000 Hz, the impedance of 1uF is 159 ohms. The impedance of 0.03uF piezo at 1KHz is 159/0.03= j4,800 ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High impedance generally means that as a source, the source impedance is high. And by high, it can also mean that the signal from the sensor needs
 to be amplified and the amplifier needs to have a high input impedance. If the load impedance on the sensor is low, it will pull the sensor voltage lower and create error in the sensor measurement.

Comment: In my case the source impedance is Xc correct?

Comment: Is ampllifer’s huge input impedance providing frequency independence ?.

Comment: If you compensate it correctly to the sensor's impedance

Comment: What do u mean by compensation?

Comment: Frequency compensation in the feedback loop, like integrators, filters differentiators

Comment: Is that something related to oscillation?

Comment: Feedback loops oscillate if not compensated correctly.

Comment: I see good tip thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The comments try discreetly quide your thinking to the right direction without putting the truth straightly against your face. The brutal technical fact is that whatever you connect to your sensor output, it needs some current. Generally you can see there's a resistor as the load. Together with your capacitor they are a high pass filter. The slower are the voltage changes the more they attenuate in the hp filter. If you know the capacitance and the frequency range of the acceleration, you can calculate the needed minimum load resistance for a given error due the filtering.

Learn RC high pass filter.

Comment: If C is very high and the frequency is very high then Xc becomes almost zero so the sensor becomes a low impedance. Since there is such dependency why are these sensors called high Z. There must be some typical values for C and f for such sensors then. What are they roughly?

Comment: Your sensor doesn't work properly at frequencies beyond the range that the manufacturer has specified in the datasheet. The range can be for ex. from 1Hz to 10kHz. If the piezo crystal has capacitance = 1000pF (=imagination) the average reactance  is about 30 kOhms. That's not especially little, At 1Hz it's about 160 MOhm.  You should consider Hi-Z as a description for the needed load resistance. Many practical sensors surely have the needed Hi-Z input preamp integrated and they output standard instrumentation signals.

Comment: Something like a small diaphragm capacitor mic element (Without its fet buffer) will be maybe 30pF, and you want to be reasonably flat to below 50Hz....

Comment: @DanMills Is the model for a piezoelectric sensor in my question wrong? (Not related to your comment)

Comment: @HelpMee "If C is very high and the frequency is very high" -- In practice the two are not both true. The capacitance of a piezoelectric sensor is very low, and the frequency at which it is useful is also low, in the grand scheme of things. You won't be using them at GHz frequencies, and their capacitance isn't on the order of mF.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term "high" comes from radio broadcasting, and the commercial audio realm, pre-1970s.

In the Morse-code radio era before vacuum tubes, headphones were either of telephone-receiver type (magnetic speaker,) or of piezo crystal type.  Across the audio spectrum, the coils-phones have low impedance, well below 1K, while the crystal headphones have far higher impedance.

Years later, up until the 1970s, normal microphones have a few hundred ohms output impedance (since microphones are dynamic mics; coil/magnets-based, before the arrival of cheap electret microphones.)   Loudspeakers are "low impedance" as well, Zinp of 8ohms, or perhaps 4ohms, or 72ohms.

After the 1970s, along come piezo devices, with impedance far, far higher than loudspeakers, higher than microphones, higher than anything except those 1920s-era crystal headphones.   From that viewpoint, piezos are "high" impedance, with "high" meaning "far higher than loudspeakers and coil-based microphones," measured at audio frequencies.